# Using Tabman paging view controller, Can the default tab order be changed to RTL?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm using the Tabman paging view controller and would like to change the order of appearance to Right-to-Left, so that the right tab will be the first to show.
Is it possible to do so? 
And is it possible to choose a specific tab (for example, tab 3 of 6) to be the first to appear? Without changing the inner order of the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any specific property for RTL order. Use below method

```
 func viewController(for pageboyViewController: PageboyViewController,
                        at index: PageboyViewController.PageIndex) -> UIViewController? {
     // Your View Controller
    }
```

For specific tab you can use below delegate method.

```
func defaultPage(for pageboyViewController: PageboyViewController) -> PageboyViewController.Page?
```

Comment: Thank you @Toseef,  I ended up using `func defaultPage(for pageboyViewController: PageboyViewController) -> PageboyViewController.Page? {
        return .last
    } (`with `.last`) for the RTL order.